# ASP.NET two forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have been trying to integrate the jquery file upload component into my project. Currently it works fine when there is only that component on the page.

The component uses the `form` tag as the drag and drop area on the page. This is an issue since there can be only one `form` tag in an asp.net web form page. In addition, the form tag defines the action that uploads the file.

This is how the form code looks like:

```
        <form id="fileupload" action="api/FileHandler" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I want this component to be in the middle of the page. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks.

EDIT: [This is the file upload component](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)!

I am using this [example](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/tree/master/Examples/_HowTos/ASPNETWebForms)!

Comment: You can try a workaround like [in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26018625/1810243).

Comment: "there can be only one form tag in an asp.net web form page" is a common misconception. *It is not true.* You can have as many form tags on a page as you want, as per HTML specification. What you *can't* have is 1) Nested forms (HTML spec) or 2) Multiple forms with `runat="server"` that are *visible* at the same time (ASP.NET spec).

Comment: Well in this case the forms need to be nested as the upload component needs to be part of the form.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, I just changed the form tag to a div with the same ID and it worked. Thanks a bunch both of you guys.

Comment: You should post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the link that @MikeSmithDev suggested I changed the form tag into a div tag and that fixed it. It seems having a form and an action where not being used as a form. The JQuery code did the setup of the drag and drop area, setup the event, and raised the event based on the tag with the specified ID. So the form tag was not really necessary.